# Validity of Open Online IQ test

Tags: intelligence, iq

I want to measure IQ of college students for a research project I am working on.

After searching for valid IQ test for research that is also low cost/free, I came across this site-https://openpsychometrics.org/

They have an IQ test listed as,The Full scale IQ test (https://openpsychometrics.org/tests/FSIQ/)

They also have listed some research papers that they claim have used their data
(https://openpsychometrics.org/_rawdata/cited/) but I simply used my browser search option to search for the terms "IQ" and "Intelligence" in that page, with O results.

Is the full scale IQ test valid and useable  for publishable academic research work? Shall I administer their test on a sample from my target population and use it for my research work?
 If not, what are some other free or low cost options avaible for me?

Comment: Related: [Free online intelligence test with norm table, high reliability, and must be printable?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/199/7001), [Why might a person get widely varying scores on different online IQ tests?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9504/7001).

Answer (score 1):

The Full scale IQ test from that source is an online IQ test that claims to measure IQ with an overall score as well as scores for component abilities, such as short-term memory, reasoning, and verbal. The test is based on the model of intelligence proposed by Hampshire, Highfield, Parkin and Owen (2012), which they claim fits best on internet populations. The test consists of six sections, each with its own instructions, and takes about 10 to 15 minutes to complete. The test provides immediate, free results without requiring personal data or fees. There are many other free online sources that I find pretty similar to the official test like https://iqtestonline.io/.

However, the validity and reliability of this test are questionable, as there is no evidence of its psychometric properties or its alignment with other established IQ tests. The test does not provide any information about its norm group, its standard deviation, or its correlation with other measures of intelligence. The test also does not account for the possible effects of test-taking conditions, such as motivation, attention, and cheating, on the test results. The test also has some limitations and biases, such as its cultural and linguistic specificity, its narrow and abstract content, and its lack of adaptive difficulty.

Therefore, I would not recommend using this test for publishable academic research work, as it may not meet the standards of scientific rigor and validity. You may face challenges and criticisms from reviewers and peers if you use this test as a measure of intelligence for your research project.

There are some other options for IQ testing that may be more suitable for research purposes, but they may not be free or low cost. Some of the most widely used and validated IQ tests are:

•  The Stanford-Binet Intelligence Scale (SBIS), which measures five factors of intelligence: fluid reasoning, knowledge, quantitative reasoning, visual-spatial processing, and working memory. It also provides a composite score, which is the overall measure of intelligence. The SBIS is suitable for ages 2 to 85, and it has a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15. The SBIS is administered by a trained professional and costs about 200 - 300 dollar per test.

•  The Wechsler Intelligence Scale for Children (WISC), which measures four domains of intelligence: verbal comprehension, perceptual reasoning, working memory, and processing speed. It also provides a full-scale IQ score, which is the overall measure of intelligence. The WISC is suitable for ages 6 to 16, and it has a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15. The WISC is administered by a trained professional and costs about 200 - 300 dollar per test.

•  The Wechsler Adult Intelligence Scale (WAIS), which measures the same four domains of intelligence as the WISC, but with different subtests and items. It also provides a full-scale IQ score, which is the overall measure of intelligence. The WAIS is suitable for ages 16 to 90, and it has a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15. The WAIS is administered by a trained professional and costs about  200 - 300 dollar per test.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer; can you add some references, preferably to journal papers?